# GAE Datastore How to delete several objects of Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I use this example for my application:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej3/index.html
I want to delete several objects of the Entity which have the same value:

```
public void removeCategory(Categories category) {
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory().getPersistenceManager();
category = pm.getObjectById(Categories.class, category.getCategoryName());
List<Categories> allCategories = listCategories();// receive all Categories
List<Categories> listCategoriesToDelete = new ArrayList<Categories>();
for (Categories nowCategory : allCategories){
if (nowCategory.getChildrenPath().indexOf(category.getCategoryName())!=-1){
listCategoriesToDelete.add(nowCategory);
}
}// works good
pm.close();
Categories[] arrayCategoriesToDelete = listCategoriesToDelete.toArray(new Categories[listCategoriesToDelete.size()]);

for (int i = 0; i<arrayCategoriesToDelete.length; i++){
PersistenceManager pm1 = getPersistenceManagerFactory().getPersistenceManager();
            try {
            pm1.currentTransaction().begin();
            pm1.deletePersistent(arrayCategoriesToDelete[i]);
            pm1.currentTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        pm1.currentTransaction().rollback();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } finally {
        pm1.close();
    }
} // ERROR
```

I have this exception:
Object with id "CD" is managed by a different Object Manager.
CD - is i value of categoryName property of Categories entity.
What I have to do to delete only several objects (lines, rows) of Entity?
Thanks.